# My cron tasks report command not found

Tags: ubuntu, bash, shell, cron

This is the contents of my crontab file:

```
0 0,6,12,18 * * * cd /var/www/app/current && backup perform --trigger db_backup --config_file config/backup.rb --data-path db --log-path log --tmp-path tmp >> /var/www/app/current/log/cron.log 2>&1

0 3 * * * cd /var/www/app/current && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake runs:populate --silent >> /var/www/app/current/log/cron.log 2>&1

59 23 * * * cd /var/www/app/current && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake runs:log --silent >> /var/www/app/current/log/cron.log 2>&1
```

If I run any of these manually as the owner of the crontab they work fine, but the `cron.log` file simply contains:

```
/bin/sh: bundle: not found
/bin/sh: backup: not found
/bin/sh: bundle: not found
```

I tried wrapping each one in the following (as default by the [whenever gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever) which I'm using to manage my cron file) `bash -l -c '...'` but then I get the same as above except for bash `bash: bundle: command not found`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The deafult PATH for CRON jobs is usually `/usr/bin:/bin`. Your commands `bundle` and `backup` are likely not in the default path. One solution is to change your crontab and include the full path to these commands.

```
0 0,6,12,18 * * * cd /var/www/app/current && /path/to/backup ...
```

etc. In general it's a good idea to use full paths in crontabs. 
If you want you can also specify the PTH inside the crontab

```
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/path/to/your/program

0 0,6,12,18 * * * cd /var/www/app/current && backup ...
```

Comment: Is there a way to add to the default path for cron so I don't have to provide the full path for each command?

Comment: Yes you can specify a PATH in the crontab file - see my edit

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can set path before actual crontab records, eg:

```
PATH=/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:
0 3 * * * run-cron-job
```