# "Command not found"-unable to run the bash script

Tags: bash, command-line-interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My cron tasks report command not found](https://serverfault.com/questions/318638/my-cron-tasks-report-command-not-found)

I am trying to run a bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

export AWS_CLOUDWATCH_URL=https://monitoring.amazonaws.com

# get ec2 instance id
instanceid=`wget -q -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id`

memtotal=`free -m | grep 'Mem' | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 2`
memfree=`free -m | grep 'buffers/cache' | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 4`
let "memused=100-memfree*100/memtotal"

mon-put-data --metric-name "FreeMemoryMBytes" --namespace "System/Linux" --dimensions "InstanceId=$instanceid" --value "$memfree" --u$

mon-put-data --metric-name "UsedMemoryPercent" --namespace "System/Linux" --dimensions "InstanceId=$instanceid" --value "$memused" --$
```

I have added this bash script in the cron but when I checked the cron it says command not found thats "mon-put-data"

when I just type the commands it runs fine. Whats the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that the `mon-put-data` command is not in a standard path. From the terminal, you can check this by typing `which mon-put-data`, then try to use the full path in the script.

This is because a bash script launched from cron won't read your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`, which may override the default path.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the full path to mon-put-data.  From your command line you can find this with:

`which mon-put-data`

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the same shell? Check. You might be using `csh` in terminal and the script might  use `bash`.

Comment: the question has a 'bash' tag

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the user that executes the script does not have the same environment (specifically, not the same PATH) that you do.

Additionally, I would suggest you use $(command) instead of `command`, as the latter is deprecated and can cause problems with quoting.

Comment: The obsolescence of the backticks is worth mentioning indeed...